# PHP login error with following message

Tags: php

I am new to PHP. I am trying to log in but it always gives me the following message:

> 'Invalid user name or password, Try again'.

Please if anyone could help me , I would greatly appreciate it.

```
<?php

$errors = array(
    1=>"Invalid user name or password, Try again",
    2=>"Please login to access this area"
);

$error_id = isset($_GET['err']) ? (int)$_GET['err'] : 0;

if ($error_id == 1) {
    echo '<p class="text-danger">'.$errors[$error_id].'</p>';
} elseif ($error_id == 2) {
    echo '<p class="text-danger">'.$errors[$error_id].'</p>';
}
?>
<h2 id="loginfont">Login Page</h2>
<br/><br/>
<fieldset style="font-family: Arial; background-color: lightblue; color: rgb(0,0,100)">
<legend style="font-variant: small-caps; font-weight:bold"> Login Form </legend>
<form name="LoginForm" method="POST" action="authenticate.php">
<label style="position: relative; line-height: 2; margin: 10px 0px"> Username: <input placeholder="Type K-number" style="position: absolute; margin-left: 20px; width: 15am; left: 80px" type="text" name="username" /> <span style="color: red">*</span> </label> <br/>
<label style="position: relative; line-height: 2; margin: 10px 0px"> Password: <input type="password" placeholder="Type Password" style="position: absolute; margin-left: 20px; width: 15am; left: 80px" type="text" name="password" /> <span style="color: red">*</span> </label> <br/>
<input type="submit" value="Login" /> <input type="reset" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Here is my authenticate.php code:

```
    <?php 
        require 'database.php';

        session_start();

        $username = "";
        $pass = "";

        if(isset($_POST['username'])){
            $username = $_POST['username'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
            $password = $_POST['password'];

        }

        echo $username ." : ".$password;

        $q = 'SELECT * FROM username WHERE username=:username AND password=:password';

        $query = $db->prepare($q);

        $query->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => $password));


        if($query->rowCount() == 0){
            header('Location: index.php?err=1');
        }else{

            $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION['sess_user_id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['sess_username'] = $row['username'];
            $_SESSION['sess_userrole'] = $row['role'];

            echo $_SESSION['sess_userrole'];
            session_write_close();

            if( $_SESSION['sess_userrole'] == "0"){
                header('Location: adminpage.php');
            }else{
                header('Location: studentpage.php');
            }               
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Don't redirect, add error handling / display and see if you get any messages.

Comment: Is your password really plan text in your db?

Comment: seems like 0 results where found.  are you getting any error messages?  what happens when you enter query directly into mysql?

Comment: why do you have your `<fieldset>` before `<form>`?

Comment: [`PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object. If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109774/pdorowcount-vs-count

Comment: even if i dont redirect i still get the same message

Comment: @bart2puck no i am not getting any error messages, basically it doesn't do much other then printing out the above message 'Invalid user name or password, Try again'.

Comment: well, this is returning true $query->rowCount() == 0   so....is password plain text, are you forgetting to convert to some hash?  does this u/p actually exist in db?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try replacing query line with this:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM username WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
```

The problem might be because you're missing the single quotes around the username and password. It looks like the actual query you're generating looks like this at the moment, so it doesn't know what jsmith and hello123 are:

```
SELECT * FROM username WHERE username=jsmith AND password=hello123;
```

Comment: That's a *terrible* answer. He was using a prepared statement, and you've introduced an SQL injection attack!

Comment: Well, then use mysql_real_escape_string($q); after that.

Comment: If that worked, then the issue may just be you need spaces between the `=:` -> `$q = 'SELECT * FROM username WHERE username = :username AND password = :password';` Do not use `... username='$username' AND password='$password'"` that was suggested in this answer, as that opens you to sql injection, that was avoided when you used prepared statement/parameters.

Comment: @user3842536 you don't use `mysql_real_escape_string()` with `PDO`. you are suggestion to use the deprecated `mysql_*` functions, where the OP is using `PDO`.