# How to use 'INSERT INTO IGNORE' with an OR clause or 'NOT EXISTS' in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a table named as `equipment` and  table schema is as follows

```
+----+-----------------+-------------------+--+----------------------+
| id |    equipment    | cat_id(Default:1) |  | is_active(Default:1) |
+----+-----------------+-------------------+--+----------------------+
|  1 | Air Compressor  |                 1 |  |                    1 |
|  2 | Plate Compactor |                 1 |  |                    1 |
|  3 | Hammer          |                 1 |  |                    1 |
|  4 | TNT             |                 1 |  |                    1 |
+----+-----------------+-------------------+--+----------------------+
```

I want to "insert records into table if the `id` and `equipment` does not exists in the table". And I have done it using following code

```
        /* equipment is an associative array 
            Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [name] => Air Compressor
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [name] => Plate Compactor
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 3
                        [name] => Hammer
                    )
            )
        */
        foreach ($equipment as $key)
        {
            $name = $key['name'];
            $id = $key['id'];
            $equipment_query = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO equipment_master (id,equipment) VALUES (:equipment_id,:equipment_name)");
            $equipment_query->bindParam('equipment_name', $name);
            $equipment_query->bindParam('equipment_id', $id);
            $equipment_query->execute();
        }
```

But problem while inserting the rows is that, I don't want to use `id` field in the query because it is `AUTO INCREMENTAL` and `Primary Key`.

Problem would occur when, if I'm trying to insert `id=>4` `equipment=>Helmet`. This record will not be inserted because `id=>4` is already in the table.

Is there a way to check if `id` is present already in the table, if not then insert the row. I tries it using `NOT EXISTS` query but my code seems to insert each row repetitively (4 to be exact)

```
        foreach ($equipment as $key)
        {
            $name = $key['name'];
            $id = $key['id'];

            $equipment_query = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO equipment_master (equipment) SELECT :equipment_name FROM equipment_master AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM equipment_master WHERE id =:equipment_id OR equipment=:equipment_name)");
            $equipment_query->bindParam('equipment_name', $name);
            $equipment_query->bindParam('equipment_id', $id);
            $equipment_query->execute();
        }
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: you can try running a rowCount on SELECT http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php but isn't always reliable. Using `count()` would work better with PDO. See this Q&A about it http://stackoverflow.com/q/19109774/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create unique index on field: equipment

   ALTER TABLE `equipment` ADD UNIQUE `equipment_unique` (`equipment`);
2. do insert ignoring errors:

   ```
   foreach ($equipment as $key)
   {
       $name = $key['name'];
       $equipment_query = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO equipment_master (equipment) VALUES (:equipment_name)");
       $equipment_query->bindParam('equipment_name', $name);
       $equipment_query->execute();
   }
   ```

but if You want replace record that has same id so You can use:

```
foreach ($equipment as $key)
{
    $name = $key['name'];
    $id = $key['id'];

    $equipment_query = $this->conn->prepare("REPLACE INTO equipment_master (id, equipment) VALUES (:equipment_id, :equipment_name)");
    $equipment_query->bindParam('equipment_name', $name);
    $equipment_query->bindParam('equipment_id', $id);
    $equipment_query->execute();
}
```

Comment: @fred-ii ,  Thank You

Comment: thanks a bunch :), that worked and I also found out the problem in my `not exists` query. I have posted the correct query below. Please check if it is correct.

Comment: it's also solution but it's better to do it without query inside of query

Comment: what problem would it cause?

Comment: no problem, just You're making select before inserting, so it may cause additional load if table will become big

Answer (score 1):

You have to create unique index on id and equipment column to use the "INSERT IGNORE".

Here is the query to create index:

```
ALTER TABLE `equipment ` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`id`, `equipment );
```

Comment: OP states: *"I don't want to use id field in the query because it is AUTO INCREMENTAL and Primary Key."*

Comment: Then you can setup multiple field as primary key. Here is the way to do that : ALTER TABLE equipment 
ADD PRIMARY KEY (id, equipment);  Make sure that you have dropped out old primary key before doing this.

Comment: MySQL only lets you have "one" primary key.

Comment: See this link : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57548/how-to-set-up-multiple-fields-as-primary-key-in-mysql

Comment: Technically you were correct. You can have one primary key per table, but it can consist of more than one column (be a composite key)

Answer (score 0):

As @num8er suggested, that solution also worked for me. And another workaround for `not exists` query is (without creating index on `equipment`) as follows,

`INSERT INTO equipment_master (equipment) SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'Plate Compactor12') AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT equipment FROM equipment_master WHERE equipment = 'Plate Compactor12' or id=1)`

this will not insert `equipment=>Plate Compactor12` because `id` is already present in table.